# How to get queryset of objects in many to many field in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two models Student and Classroom in models.py

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    classroom_subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    classroom_code = models.CharField(max_length= 5, default = '00000')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Classroom, blank = True)
```

I have three tables in my database

student:

| user_id | student_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |

classroom:

| id | classroom_subject | classroom_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | maths | 12345 |
| 2 | english | 12345 |
| 3 | biology | 12345 |

student_classes:

| id | student_id | classroom_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

In my views.py

```
class StudentClassesView(ListView):
    model = Classroom
    template_name = 'student_classroom_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'classroom_list'

    
    def get_queryset(self):
        student_id = self.request.user.id
        return Student.classes.through.objects.filter(
        )
```

This code returns all the classrooms in student_classes, but i want it to return all the classrooms where the student_id = self.request.user.id

So for example self.request.user.id returns 4, I want all the classrooms in student_classes table where student_id = 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with:

```
Classroom.objects.filter(
    student__user=request.user
)
```

This will retrieve all `Classroom`s for which a related `Student` has as `user` the `request.user`.

Comment: Also you can do it by overriding get method of class `ListView` that you inherited. Let me to know if it's not good idea @WillemVanOnsem .

Comment: YES! Thank you it worked, been trying to fix that for hours. Classroom.objects.filer() filters all the classroom objects, does student__user refers to the user object in student?

Comment: @calvincode123: indeed.